# View xcodebuild analyze results in a jenkins build

Tags: xcode, jenkins, static-analysis, xcodebuild

I'm using Xcode Jenkins plugin to run my xcode builds.
The analyze step is setup in the job using xcodebuild analyze argument.

Is it possible to setup jenkins job to see the results of the analyze in some human readable way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can use Warnings plugin for Jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin).

It allows to parse xcodebuild output and fetch compile warnings.